# No suitable contstructors found java error..?

Tags: java

```
public class CustomerTest
{
    private static Object CustomerType;
  public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String msg = "";
        ArrayList(Customer) cList;

        ArrayList<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<Customer>();

        Customer c1 = new Customer ("Jones", new Address("Cooper","Arlington", "Texas", 76019), 12345);
        Customer c2 = new Customer ("Smith", new Address("Bowen","Arlington", "Texas", 76006), 65489);
        Customer c3 = new Customer ("willis", new Address("Bowen","Arlington", "Texas",75550), 27589);

        customerList.add(c1);
        customerList.add(c2);
        customerList.add(c3);
        ArrayList<Course> courseList = new ArrayList<Course>();

                Course co1 = new Course ("OnlineCourse",("Java 1","PROGRAMMING", "Davis", 125.00, new Date(1,1,2015), new Date(1,15,2015), "Uta" 2015);
                Course co2 = new Course ("OnlineCourse","Java 2","Jones", 125.00, new Date(1,1,2015), new Date(1,15,2015));
        Course co3 = new Course ("InClassCourse","CanonPictures", "Long", 75.00, new Date(2,5,2015), new Date(3,2,2015));

        courseList.add(co1);
        courseList.add(co2);
        courseList.add(co3);

        c1.setCType(Customer.customerType.STUDENT);
        c2.setCType(Customer.customerType.FACULTY);
        c3.setCType(Customer.customerType.GOVERNMENT);


         for (Customer c: customerList)
         {
          cList = c.getCustomerList();
          for (Customer c: cList)
          {
            msg += c.calculateCharge();
          }
         }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg);
    } 
}
```

Getting "No suitable constructors found" In Course c01, co2.

It's also not letting me set STUDENT, FACULTY, etc.. it's giving me a "cannot find symbol" I have 6 classes and this is the main class. I declared all the variables, sets, gets in other classes and now I'm trying to execute the main class(this one) OKAY I ADDED THE CLASSES THE MAIN USES.

```
public class Course
{

    private String title;
    private String instructor;
    private double price;
    public enum CourseType{PROGRAMMING, MATHEMATICS, PHOTOGRAPHY, MUSIC, PAINTING, MISC};
    private CourseType cType;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;

    public Course()

    {
                setTitle("");
            setInstructor("");
        setPrice(0.0);
        setCType(CourseType.PROGRAMMING);
        setStartDate(new Date());
        setEndDate(new Date());
        }
    public Course(String title, String instructor, double price, Date startDate, Date endDate)

    {
                setTitle(title);
                setInstructor(instructor);
                setPrice(price);
                setStartDate(startDate);
                setEndDate(endDate);         

    }
    public void setTitle(String title)

    {
        this.title = title;

    }
    public void setInstructor(String instructor)

    {

        this.instructor = instructor;

    }
    public void setPrice(double price)

    {
        this.price = price;

    }
    public void setCType(CourseType cType)

    {
        this.cType = cType;

    }
    public void setStartDate(Date startDate)

    {
        this.startDate = startDate;

    }
    public void setEndDate(Date endDate)

    {
        this.endDate = endDate;

    }
    public String getTitle()

    {
        return title;

    }
    public String getInstructor()

    {
        return instructor;

    }
    public double getPrice()

    {
        return price;

    }
    public CourseType getCType()

    {
        return cType;

    }
    public Date getStartDate()

    {
        return startDate;

    }
    public Date getEndDate()

    {
        return endDate;

    }
    public double calculateCharge(Customer.CustomerType c)

    {
        return 0.0;

    }

    public String toString()

    {
        return("title" + title + "instructor" + instructor + "price" + price + "cType" + cType);

    }
} 

public class Customer
{

    private String name;
    private Address address;
    private int accountNumber;
    public enum CustomerType{STUDENT, FACULTY, GOVERNMENT};
    private CustomerType cType;
    private ArrayList<Course> courseList = new ArrayList<Course>();

    public Customer()

    {

        setName("");
        setAddress(new Address());
        setAccountNumber(0);
    }
    public Customer(String name, Address address, int accountNumber)

    {
        setName(name);
        setAddress(address);
        setAccountNumber(accountNumber);
    }
    public void setName(String name)

    {
        this.name = name;

    }
    public void setAddress(Address address)

    {
        this.address = address;

    }
    public void setAccountNumber(int accountNumber)

    {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;

    }
    public void setCType(CustomerType cType)
    {
        this.cType = cType;

    }
    public void addCourse(Course course)

    {
        courseList.add(course);

    }
    public String getName()

    {
        return name;

    }
    public Address getAddress()

    {
        return address;

    }
    public CustomerType getCType()

    {
        return cType;

    }
    public String getCourseList()

    {
        return courseList.toString();

    }
    public String toString()

    {
        return("name" + name + "Address" + address + "accountnumber" + accountNumber + "CustomerType" + cType + "courseList" + courseList);

        }

}
```

Comment: Missing comma perhaps?  ` new Date(1,15,2015), "Uta" 2015); ` at end of Course c01 line?

Comment: `ArrayList(Customer)` should be `ArrayList<Customer>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the constructors you have supplied.

```
public Course(String title, String instructor, double price, Date startDate, Date endDate)

public Course()
```

And based on the Course c01 object it looks like you have a couple of issues. First a misplaced parentheses (, and "Uta" 2015, aren't valid for the constructor either.

```
Course co1 = new Course ("OnlineCourse",("Java 1","PROGRAMMING", "Davis", 125.00, new Date(1,1,2015), new Date(1,15,2015), "Uta" 2015);
```

---

I am not sure if it was just a typo, but there is no suitable constructors, just as the errors states.

Try to replace that with this and see what you get.

```
Course co1 = new Course ("Java 1","Davis", 125.00, new Date(1,1,2015), new Date(1,15,2015));
```

---

For the cannot find symbol error it looks like you might not be referring to the enum correctly.

```
c1.setCType(Customer.customerType.STUDENT);
```

When it looks like it should be,

```
c1.setCType(Customer.CustomerType.STUDENT);
```

---

Comment: Edit your question, and add your source code for the other classes.

Comment: Looks like that did it! I'll use this example for the rest of co2 and co3.             I'm Also getting "cannot find symbol" for CustomerType.STUDENT      in the CustomerTest class.